# Getting Error by Uploading Youtube Videos in my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video

I WANT TO UPLOAD YOUTUBE VIDEOS in my App.

I always get two errors in my console.

1. `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:3000').`
2. `Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ch-ua-form-factor'.`

I only get keys from the Movie databse Api to show videos. Can somebody help what did I wrong?

Video.jsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Video.css'
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';


export default function Video(props) {
  
  const opts = {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    playerVars: {
      // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
      autoplay: 0,
    },
  };

  return (
    <div className='videos'>
        {props.videosList.results.map((element) => {
            if(element.type === "Trailer"){
                return <YouTube videoId={`${element.key}`} opts={opts} key={element.id}/>;
            } else {
                return null
            }
        })
        }
    </div>
  )
}
```